Is the set of Turing machines with state size limited to at most some constant still Turing-complete?
I learned that if the alphabet is limited to some constant size, e.g. {0,1} and maybe some special characters, we can still construct any Turing machine by simply expanding the state and encoding each original alphabet symbol in 0/1s.
I was wondering if the same is true if we limit the state to some constant size, e.g. 2 (but allow the tape alphabet to be arbitrarily big). Is this equally as expressive as Turing machines?

If you have a constant bound on the size of the alphabet and on the number of states, there are only a finite number of possible Turing machines, thus they can only compute finitely many languages.

Unless you consider multitape machines. Then yes, this is Turing complete, as you can just represent the state by the symbol read at sufficiently many work tapes.

Sorry I meant also allowing tape alphabet to now be arbitrarily big, edited to clarify

Ah, all right, that makes sense. Then this is Turing complete. I believe even 2 states are enough.

Isn't this just a register machine?

Yes, this is as expressive as all Turing machines.
It is easy to see how to do it with 5 states. Let $M$ be a TM that you want to simulate, with work alphabet $\Gamma$ and set of states $Q=\{q_0,\dots,q_t\}$, where $q_0$ is the initial state. The simulating machine $M'$ will use work alphabet $\Gamma'=\Gamma\times Q$, encoding both the symbols of $M$ and (in the position of the head) the current state. All symbols not under the current head position will be written as $(a,q_0)$, disregarding the actual current state. Let us identify a symbol $a\in\Gamma$ with $(a,q_0)\in Q\times\Gamma$, so that when the machine starts, the input written on the tape is already suitably encoded.
When $M'$ is in the “normal state”, it will simulate one step of $M$: it reads the current symbol and state, and based on the transition function of $M$, writes a new symbol and new state. Then, depending on the direction in which the head is supposed to move, it will enter a state “move right” or “move left”.
The goal of the “move right” state is to gradually move the current state indicator one position to the right. So, if the current symbol is $(a,q_{i+1})$, it will replace it with $(a,q_i)$, move right, and go to state “return left”. In the “return left” state, the machine will replace the current symbol $(a',q_j)$ with $(a',q_{j+1})$, and move left, going back to the “move right” state. If, in the “move right” state, the symbol is $(a,q_0)$, the transition is done: the machine moves right and enters the “normal state”.
The “move left” and “return right” states work dually.
With some effort, the number of states can be reduced to just 2. Let us use work alphabet $\Gamma'=\Gamma\times Q\times\{L,R,M\}$, where the $L/R$ part indicates whether the position is to the right or left of the current head position: symbols to the right of the head will be written as $(a,q_0,R)$, and to the left of the head as $(a,q_0,L)$. We identify $a$ with $(a,q_0,R)$. $M$ indicates we are in the middle of a move (see below).
We assume $M$ uses a one-way infinite tape such that the machine starts at the left end-position, and never attempts to move left past the end (the latter can be enforced by marking the position by a special symbol as the first thing $M$ does). $M'$ will obey the same restrictions, thus it will also work the same way if you interpret it on a two-way infinite tape, if you prefer tht model. The goal of all this is to make sure the initial input of $M'$ is suitably encoded: all positions represent $(a,q_0,R)$, and this is fine as there are no positions to the left of the initial head position.
The machine will use two states, $L$ (which is the initial state) and $R$. They will simulate the 5 states above as follows:

If the state is $L$ and the current symbol $(a,q_i,R)$, or if the state is $R$ and the current symbol $(a,q_i,L)$, this indicates the “normal state”. The machine updates $a$ and $q_i$ to the new values, writing them as $(a,q_i,M)$. Depending on whether it is supposed to go right or left, it will enter state $R$ or $L$.

State $R$ with current symbol $(a,q_i,M)$ behaves as “move right”: if $i>0$, it decreases $i$ and moves right (in the same state). If $i=0$, it writes $(a,q_0,L)$ and moves right, going to the $L$ state (i.e., “normal state”).

State $R$ with current symbol $(a',q_j,R)$ behaves as “return left”: write $(a',q_{j+1},R)$ and move left (still in state $R$).

State $L$ with current symbol $(a,q_i,M)$ or $(a',q_j,L)$ behaves dually, simulating “move left” and “return right”.


The final thing to discuss is how to end the computation.
If your machine model requires that the machine only halts by moving to a special accept/reject state, you have to include these states as well, there is no way around it.
Another common machine model is that the transition function may be partial, and the machine halts when the current transition is undefined; the set of states is partitioned into accepting and rejecting states, and the machine accepts or reject accordingly when it halts. This can be easily accommodated here: we make, say, $L$ an accepting state and $R$ a rejecting state; when $M'$ detects in the “normal state” that $M$ is supposed to halt, it goes to state $L$ or $R$ according to whether it is supposed to accept or reject, and writes on the tape something on which the transition function will be undefined.
This all works for decision problems, where the only output of the machine is acceptance. If we care about the output written on the tape as well, we need a third state after all so that we can decode the output to the original tape alphabet after acceptance. (We could make sure $M$ can halt only at the left-most position of the tape, hence only the current symbol needs converting from $(a,q_i,?)$ to $a=(a,q_0,R)$, but I do not see how to arrange that without an extra state, since $(a,q_0,R)$ in states $L$ and $R$ already has a different meaning.)
